# Python Data frame to CSV - Converting to Windows Filepath

Tags: python, dataframe, filepath

The following code works for me on the MAC OS but I'm having trouble converting it to a windows file path.  If I just make the forward slashes into back slashes the file turns to color red as if it is a literal.

dict=pd.DataFrame(elements_count, index=[0,])

dict.to_csv(path+'/Word_freq/'file+'.csv')

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.path.join`

```py
import os
fullPath = os.path.join(path,'Word_freq', file + '.csv')
```

In fact, I'd always prefer `os.path.join` over string concatenation, cause it will join the path based on the `platform`
But if you still want to use string concatenation, then you can join the path, directory, subdirectory, or file name using separting them by by `os.sep`
Like this:

```py
fullPath = path + os.sep + 'Word_freq' + os.sep + file + '.csv'
```

Comment: You are the myth and the legend!  It worked.  Thank you!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked for you!